# Image colors change when applying transparency mask in Opencv, Pillow

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am using OpenCV and Pillow to apply a mask to make the background transparent for an image using the code below, but the output images are comparatively faded. How do I properly apply these masks? Is there another way, or another library to obtain correct transparent images.

**opencv code:**

```
image= cv2.imread(path)
mask = cv2.imread(path)
b,g,r=cv2.split(image)
mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
op = cv2.merge([b,g,r,mask])
cv2.imwrite("opencv.png",op)
```

**Pillow**

```
image= Image.open(path)
mask = Image.open(path).convert("L")
empty = Image.new("RGBA", image.size, 0)
output_file = Image.composite(image, empty, mask)
output_file.save("pillow.png")
```

Attaching here the input, output, and the required output image(Drive link since the images exceed the upload limit size)
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1n9gZCUw5Zf2jNAnjJGl5XZRtPIhDrNu-?usp=sharing

Comment: Does the input have a color profile?  Does your output? If both do not have the same profile, then colors might change.

Comment: How can I check this? and also maintain the color profile while saving the output image. Pillow does have a method to save the image in a specific color profile. I did try to save the output image using the input image's color profile, but the result was the same.

Comment: I would suggest using either ImageMagick directly or Python Wand, which uses ImageMagick. See if the same color change exists. If you post your image, I could try with ImageMagick. Also you could remove the background and put it back (or some similar color background) and see if the darkening is just an illusion. Also you could try using http://remove.bg and see if their result looks similar.

Comment: I have attached the output above as a drive link, the image "ideal output" is the output from remove.bg. I Will update after trying Wand.

Answer (score 0):

Your ideal_output.png image has an Adobe RGB profile. Your pillow_output.png has no specific profile, but PNG only supports RGB type files. So there is a change of profile. If you want to preserve the look, then add an Adobe RGB profile to your pillow output.

I can see that from ImageMagick.

```
Filename: ideal_output.png
 Profiles:
    Profile-icc: 560 bytes  <------
  Properties:
    date:create: 2020-09-22T17:17:48+00:00
    date:modify: 2020-09-21T04:53:50+00:00
    icc:copyright: Copyright 2000 Adobe Systems Incorporated
    icc:description: Adobe RGB (1998) <-----
    png:iCCP: chunk was found
    png:IHDR.bit-depth-orig: 8
    png:IHDR.bit_depth: 8
    png:IHDR.color-type-orig: 6
    png:IHDR.color_type: 6 (RGBA)
    png:IHDR.interlace_method: 0 (Not interlaced)
    png:IHDR.width,height: 408, 612
    png:pHYs: x_res=11811, y_res=11811, units=1
```

```
Filename: pillow_output.png
 Properties:
    date:create: 2020-09-22T17:17:48+00:00
    date:modify: 2020-09-21T04:55:52+00:00
    png:IHDR.bit-depth-orig: 8
    png:IHDR.bit_depth: 8
    png:IHDR.color-type-orig: 6
    png:IHDR.color_type: 6 (RGBA)
    png:IHDR.interlace_method: 0 (Not interlaced)
    png:IHDR.width,height: 3648, 5472
    png:sRGB: intent=0 (Perceptual Intent)
```